# How to recursively delete a parent record from db using mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I have a (very) complicated db structure.
One of the tables represents a customer. This table is referenced by other child- tables, and these child tables are referenced too (not necessarily tree structure).

I have to delete a parent record in the customers table, without changing constraints definitions(I do not want to use delete on cascade!!!).

I thought of to implement this recursively in mySQL, but that seems to be super complicated (in each step I have to figure if I visited the table, if its a leaf table, and save the key of the parent table so I can delete the records of the child table associated with it).

I want to use recursion and not to use the iterative way that relays on the data tables because when someone in the future enters a new table I will have to change the algorithm.. and I want it to stay consistent.

eample: 
if that is the hirarchy (tab represents a child)

customers

```
code_831
    site_sales_billings

cus_dev_devid

custom_wizard_containers
    unlock_wizard_request

customer_attendant_console
    customer_attendant_console_row

customer_attendant_consoles
    customer_region_attendant_consoles
        customer_region_attendant_console_rows
```

I want first to delete rows from the leaves tables:
site_sales_billings , cus_dev_devid, unlock_wizard_request, customer_attendant_console_row, customer_region_attendant_console_rows   and than upwords until I will have permission to delete a customer record without constraint error..

Comment: Glad this isn't my problem!

Comment: That is not helping :)

Comment: Hello @ChenLevy and welcome to stackoverflow! Your problem seems hard enough to require an example. It is hard to help out on just these words... How do you know what table is referenced and where if you are not using constraints? Help us out by giving us a slight example on how you'd do a small iteration and some blessed soul might understand your problem better.

Comment: I start with the customers table, in each step I can run sql to get the names of the tables that reference this table (the "children") and I have to delete child records.. if the table is not referenced, I can delete records from it without problem, and if not I will encounter a constraint error.. . I am not strong in mySQL (that is the main problem maybe)  to be more clear, I want to implement "Delete on cascade" without using it (without changing constraints definitions, because I am not allowed)